# javascript get object inside another if statement

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access an object inside another if statement? Because the situation is like this.

I have an edit button and it will set a `<div>` to `contenteditable`. so if I press the cancel button, the text inside the `<div>` should also reset. and now my javascript goes like this

```
$('.class').on('click','.etc',function(){
    var orig = {};
    $a = $(this).('.etc').text().trim(); // just getting the text of the button
    if($a == "Edit") // just checking if edit button
    {
        orig.text = $(this).find('original-text').text(); // should store the original text
    }
    else if ($a == "Cancel")
    {
        // the div must be set to the original text
        alert(orig.text); // undefined
    }
});
```

I'm really at lost here

Comment: Please, include HTMl code as well. Are you using JQuery?

Comment: `if` and `else` can not call at same time.

Comment: In order to get text of an element, better to use `text()` function.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out why "alert(orig.text)" is coming up undefined, or are you trying to find out why "it's not working"? It is a little unclear exactly what you are asking. It would also help to know what you have done and what has failed.

Comment: Show how is `$a` created?

Comment: Updated. Just something like this `$a = $(this).('.etc').text().trim();`

Comment: `$(this).('.etc')` <-- makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable at a scope where it is accessible by both the `if` and the `else` condition or maybe at a global scope. But make sure it's initialized before you try to access its properties!

```
var orig = {text:""};
  $('.class').on('click','.etc',function(){

    if($a == "Edit") // just checking if edit button
    {
        orig.text = $(this).find('original-text').text();
    }
    else if ($a == "Cancel")
    {
        alert(orig.text); 
    }
});
```

Comment: @iamDevlin updated the answer. Now it'll atleast have an empty string when you try to access its text property.

Comment: Still not working. I wanted to update `orig.text` to get the original text and then let the `Cancel` if statement access this `orig.text` from the `Edit` if statement.

Comment: @iamDevlin  moving it to a global scope should do it! check the update

Comment: I felt stupid. I wasn't thinking about that. I was focused on declaring the object in the event.

Comment: Even my question has a down vote hahahaha. 2am's really make me stupid.

Comment: @iamDevlin  there you go!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the scope of the variable `orig`. JS has function level lexical scope.

So to answer your title question, yes you can access a variable created in an in in `if` in the `else` so long as the `else` is sure to occur after the if has occurred at least once. But that's not really what's causing your problems.

Your issue is that you are trying to persist this variable beyond the onclick function. When that function ends so does the life of the variable. The simple fix is to declare it outside the function and utilize JS closures.

```
var orig = {};
$('.class').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "Store") {
        orig.text = $("#display").text();
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Cancel") {
        alert(orig.text);
    }
});
```

I had to adapt it a bit because I don't know your full HTML, but [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/dsud8h2y/).

---

**UPDATE**
To avoid the bad practice of global variables you can create a closed scope for the whole thing like so:

```
(function () {
    var orig = {};
    $('.class').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "Store") {
            orig.text = $("#display").text();
        } else if ($(this).text() == "Cancel") {
            alert(orig.text);
        }
    });
})();
```

[And here's that in practice](http://jsfiddle.net/dsud8h2y/1/)